# Comparing a Date in PHP

Tags: php, function, date

I am working on a php app and need some help with comparing a date.
I have a date select input field (datepicker) which thanks to client side code will always post a date in the format: mm/dd/YYYY eg 02/25/2015.

What Iam trying to do is assertain that this date is no later than the current date, using php.

Initially I have set the local timezone with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

And within the code I have:

```
} elseif (date(strtotime($_POST['datepicker'])) > date('m,d,Y')){
    $displayblock.= "<br><p>The selected date is in the future!!!       </p>".date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
$alertbox = "<script>alert('".$_POST['datepicker']." is in the future!!! Shall we try that again? :-)');</script>";
```

This is obviously far from graceful and does not appear to be comaparing dates correctly either.
Can anyone help pls?

Many Thanks,

Comment: I suppose you could use [datefdiff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) from the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). Either way, if datediff doesn't work, I'm sure you can DateTime class has something that can help you, browse around.

Comment: If you want an easy OO way to interface with time you can use https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 2):

You can also compare them if they are coming as a string with this function. The first date is your date coming from your html/javascript datepicker, the second date is the actual date of server:

```
function stringDateIsAPastDate($datestring1){
  if ((date("j-m-Y", strtotime($datestring1))) <= (date("j-m-Y"))){
    //here the code to do when the date inserted from the website is a past date or today
    return(true);
  }else{
    return(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $now = new DateTime();
    $now->format('Y-m-d');
    $ding = new DateTime($_POST['datepicker']);
    $ding->format('Y-m-d');
    if($now < $ding){
      echo 'datepicker is after current time';
    } else {
      echo 'datepicker is before current time';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Compare Two Dates**

```
$date1 = new DateTime('May 13th, 1986');
$date2 = new DateTime('October 28th, 1989');

$difference = $date1->diff($date2);
```

**Check this :** 
http://www.paulund.co.uk/datetime-php

**And php.net Manual:**
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php